# how to invoke powershell from wsl to use speech synthesizer

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell

I need to use wsl to invoke powershell to use "text to speech" in my bash script. I tried this and it run only in PS but not in wsl :

```
$sp = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SpVoice
$sp.Speak("Hello...")
```

I tried also this in wsl but it doesn't work either:

```
powershell.exe $sp = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SpVoice
powershell.exe $sp.Speak("Hello...")
```

Answer (score 2):

As $sp is considered as variable expansion, you need to use single quote :

```
powershell.exe '$sp = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SpVoice; $sp.Speak("Hello...")'
```